# Match closest to with condition (modify target)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So i have a column with a simple progression

```
A1 = 10
A2 = 20
A3 = 30 
A4 = 40 
A5 = 50
and so on.
```

How do i find the closest match not going over 24 IF the match is made against whats in the range minus fixed amount say 13.

Finding what i need matched without the -13 condition is simple:

`=MATCH(24,A1:A10,1)`   which returns 2.

However if we subtract 13 from all cells in target range. It will return 3.

I can't just subtract it from column A directly because i need different formulas to subtract different amounts for different matches.

Its kind of like a fake index , where the range its drawing from is `{10;20;30;40;50}` but we use `{-3;7;17;27;37}` instead (:

(Office 2016)

Comment: What about adding 13 to your lookup value?

Comment: @MátéJuhász wont need to. So you can skip it if that saves complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this becomes possible with arrays.

and you can just tack it on like this:

```
=MATCH( 24 , A1:A10-13  ,1)
```

works so long as you use

<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

to turn it into an array formula.